# Django 2 make comment filed error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, comments

recently I decide to add a comment block to my template in my django app but when I add it to my app , I faced to this error :

```
add_comment_to_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item_id'
```

my template.html:

```
{% block content %}
                                    <form action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        {{ form.as_p }}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <p><label>Name*</label><input type="text" name="your-name" value=""
                                                                              size="60" class=""
                                                                              aria-required="true"
                                                                              aria-invalid="false"></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <p><label>Email*</label><input type="text" name="your-email"
                                                                               value=""
                                                                               size="60" class=""
                                                                               aria-required="true"
                                                                               aria-invalid="false"></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <p><label>Website</label><input type="text" name="your-website"
                                                                                value=""
                                                                                size="60" class=""
                                                                                aria-required="true"
                                                                                aria-invalid="false"></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <p><label>Message</label><textarea name="your-message" cols="60"
                                                                                   rows="3" class=""
                                                                                   aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
                                        <p>
                                            <button type="button" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=item.pk %}"
                                                    class="btn btn-lg btn-darker">Post Comment
                                            </button>
                                        </p>
                                    </form>
                                {% endblock %}
```

my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.

class Blogs(models.Model):
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Blogs/', help_text='This Image Is Gonna To Be Show At Blogs Page.',
                                   blank=False, default='')

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Blog.Blogs', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

my form.py:

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import Blogs, Comment


    class CommentForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ('author', 'text',)

my views.py :
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from Blog.forms import CommentForm
from .models import Blogs, Comment

def item(request, items_id):
    items = get_object_or_404(Blogs, pk=items_id)
    return render(request, 'Blog/Items.html', {'item': items, 'comments': Comment})


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Blogs, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'blog/Items.html', {'form': form})
```

and my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from Blog import views
from Blog import models


urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:item_id>/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('<int:items_id>/', views.item, name='Itemz'),
]
```

I checked my code many times but I can't understand what is my problem.
is any body know to how can I add comment to my app or what is my problem?
**In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Comment: Where does **item.pk** come from? You have it in yout template, but it's not passed from the view. `href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=item.pk %}"`

Comment: item is object in my template and item.pk is passing to view in `"href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=item.pk %}"`

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem happen because in urls.py there were two subject that was pass to one views.
change views to this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.item, name='Itemz'),
]
```

then change html part to this :

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                                        <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-gr btn-xs">Login To Send
                                            A Command.</a></p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
                                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                        <form method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{ form.as_p }}
                                            <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
                                            <p>
                                                <button href="{% url 'Itemz' item.id %}" type="submit"
                                                        class="btn btn-lg btn-darker">Post Comment
                                                </button>
                                            </p>
                                        </form>
                                    {% endif %}
```

now the Django project will run properly.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
```

To:

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, item_id):
```

Then change everywhere inside the function you wrote pk to item_id

views.py

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, item_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blogs, pk=item_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/Items.html', {'form': form, 'item': post})
```

and in your template:

```
<button type="button" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' item.pk %}"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-darker">Post Comment
</button>
```

Comment: I changed it and I get this error :
`Reverse for 'add_comment_to_post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

Comment: I already do that and I changed pk to item_id in my class but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is in my .html file because my IDE say this as a warning in the line I write `<button type="button" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=item.pk %}"` and my IDE warning is : `The following arguments are missing: 'item_id'.
Django inspection that checks " {% url %} " tag for required arguments. It ensures that all arguments are passed correctly`

Comment: href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=item.pk %}" instead of pk=item.pk put **item_id=item.pk** or just do this href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' item.pk %}"

Comment: Comment your button or delete the href and reload the page. Tell me what you have

Comment: the right format is that I put `{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=item.pk %}` in button tag or put this as an action in my form tag?

Comment: Change the pk=item.pk to item_id=item.pk and do the changes in my answer. Use everywhere  in your view item_id

Comment: unfortunately I get the same error. as I understand this error happen  in `path('<int:items_id>/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),` when I change item_id in urls.py , my error is changed too.

Comment: the path should be `path('<int:item_id>/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post')` not items_id but item_id. I updated my answer

Comment: my problem solved , this happen because I pass one parameter to two different views.

Comment: That's fine then

Comment: if you dont mind I will answer to this question and put the correct code here.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your url patterns maybe? Try:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
```

The variable name in your view method needs to match the variable name in the url. Therefore you need both to be `pk` or both to be `item_id`

Comment: if I change my path to `path('<int:pk>/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),` I will face this error : `Reverse for 'add_comment_to_post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']`
and pk and items_id are the same, but pk isn't define in urls.py so I have to use `item:id` instead.